# Jquery Mobile listview gap at bottom of each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

[image]

I want to get rid of the gap at the bottom of the list view.

here is my css

```
.myParagraph.ui-li-desc {
      color:#333;
      overflow:show;
      white-space:normal;
      height:28px;
      margin-bottom:0px;
    }
```

here is my markup:

```
listitems_markup = '<li><img src="' + itemThumbnail + '""><div class="myParagraph"><p>You viewed ' + itemName + '</p><p>You spent '+itemTimeSpent+' on this activity</p><p>You '+itemRating+' this item</p></div><p class="ui-li-aside">'+itemViewedTime+'</p></li>';
```

how will I get rid of that gap?

Comment: try li.myParagraph.ui-li-desc or important to margin

Comment: @Hushme tried .li.myParagraph.ui-li-desc didnt work, how do u do important to margin?

Comment: margin-bottom:0px !important;

Comment: and which class is implementing on those list?

Comment: get that class applying on list and apply no margin on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
      listitems_markup = '<li class="nomarigin"><img src="' + itemThumbnail + '"">
<div class="myParagraph"><p>You viewed ' + itemName + '</p><p>You spent '+itemTimeSpent+' on this activity</p><p>You '+itemRating+' this item</p></div><p class="ui-li-aside">'+itemViewedTime+'</p></li>';
```

in css

```
.nomarigin {margin-bottom:0 !important;}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that, it looks much neater now, but I figured it out, It wouldn't be able get rid of the gap, because on mobile view smaller screens, the description on the listview is long, and it wraptexts into the div, so on mobile view, a bigger gap appears. it's ok, I shall leave it that way, but adding in ur nomargin makes it neater. thanks